# Passing Variables between View Controllers - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, variables, segue, sigabrt

I am trying to pass a variable (`tutorID`) to another view controller (`TimetableTableViewController`) but when the code runs the app crashes giving and error message: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

I have this inside my `TimetableTableViewController.h` (the view I'm passing the variable to):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentTutorID;
```

And this inside my `prepareForSegue` method in the view controller I'm sending the variable from:

```
NSString *tutorID = @"1";

TimetableTableViewController * timetableTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
timetableTableViewController.currentTutorID = tutorID;
```

If anyone could help me fix this error or give me another way, thank you.

EDIT

The segue is leading to a `NavigationViewController` so thats why it's crashing. Does anyone know how I can pass the variable to `TimetableTableViewController` instead of the `NavagationViewController`.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: There's nothing with with just the few lines you've posted

Comment: Having a look at the link from @rmaddy I think the problem is that there is a `NavigationViewController` before the `TimetableTableViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange that you are getting SIGABRT, it should say that your controller not responding to selector `tutorID`.

Use `[segue.destinationViewController topViewController]` to get root controller from navigation controller that you want to present.

Comment: Like this: `TimetableTableViewController *timetableTableViewController = [segue.destinationViewController topViewController];`?

Comment: exactly, if ```TimetableTableViewController``` embedded in navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is your segue is going in NavigationViewController and TimetableTableViewController is root view controller of it.

In this case [segue destinationViewController] will return NavigationViewController not TimetableTableViewController.

You can try this.

```
NavigationViewController * nav = [segue destinationViewController];
TimetableTableViewController * timetableTableViewController = nav[0];
timetableTableViewController.currentTutorID = tutorID;
```

Try this and tell me what you are getting.